# Adivce for dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

I have recently become interested in trying out Ubuntu 15.10, just for the sake of fun. However, I am confused as to how to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 on my Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7295

The computer is a rather high-spec one, with one 256 SSD on which Windows 10 is installed (as in, any important files required to run Windows 10), and a 1 TB hard drive that is used to hold any extra files, like documents and what not.

The 256 GB SSD is almost full, leaving only the 1 TB hard drive open for installing Ubuntu.

However, the computer is EFI boot, so I believe that the boot partition is on the SSD

What advice would you give me when attempting to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot set-up?

Comment: First boot into a Ubuntu Live CD/USB and provide us with a screenshot of your partition table either by using Gparted or `lsblk -f`. Someone will give specific instructions for you then..

Comment: I'd partition a space on the 1 TB drive and use EFI mode and the EFI boot management process to pick which OS I used at boot time.

Comment: Also make sure to boot your Live CD/USB in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make a different `20 GB` partition for `Ubuntu`, and with `windows`Ubuntu`installer` you can easily install `Ubuntu` on your `windows 10` like an application of you windows machine. when you are tired with `Ubuntu` just `uninstall` it from control panel just like any software.